# Email confirmation on identity using two projects (one to send the token and one to confirm)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a problem using Identity email confirmation in my ASP.NET core 3.1 application.

I have a Web API project that receives a request to register a user. With that, I generate a token for confirmation and send that token to the user's email. However, the URL configured in the email, for him to perform the confirmation, is from a Web project and when I confirm the user, the application displays the error message stating that the token is invalid even using the same database for both applications - in addition, I also use a shared identity project for these applications.

The token sent is correct, because when comparing what was sent by the API and what was received by the Web, it is the same token but when calling the method to confirm the email, the return is a message saying that the token is invalid.

**GENERATE TOKEN TO CONFIRM (API PROJECT)**

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
var callbackUrl = $"https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={user.Id}&code={code}";
var confirmationUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
```

**TOKEN CONFIRMATION (WEB PROJECT)**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
    StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Email confirmed" : "Error to confirm email.";
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the usermanger ConfirmEmailAsync will decrypt the token according to its data protection provider.

Normally, different project will use different  data protection provider. If your two application are both asp.net core applications.

I suggest you could try to use below codes to connect to the same external store and use the same application name. The external store could be a network location, mapped drive, Azure Key Vault, etc.

If you are in develop mode, you could set them to same path.

Add below codes in startup.cs configure service method:

```
 //Make sure the app name and path is same.
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("shared app name")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: This answer covers why this is not working but I would suggest instead of using File System to add them to a distributed cache like redis. I assume that the reason why you want them as separate project is for more flexibility. I would go around and try to set it up take a look at `IDistributedCache` for .Net Core and storing it to the DB if a cache is not sufficient (but I would assume you need high speed for this scenario of validation)

Comment: Saved my day, thank you. In my case only ```.SetApplicationName("shared app name")``` was enough to enable two ASPNET Core web apps to share same tokens.